# Creating a dictionary of arbitrary inputs using prefix binding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a service which is an extension to another platofrm. Since we are an extension to the platform, we don't have control over the shape of requests that are sent to us.

The platform sends a request to our API, in a body that has a single `"Properties"` object property. This object is a flat structure of parameters, and this flat structure is what we can define.

Currently our input looks like this:

```
{
  "Properties": {
    "fileLocation": {
      "value": "https://path.To.Storage/"
    },
    "account": {
      "value": "myAccountName"
    },
    "Metadata.ClientId": {
      "value": "someGuid"
    },
    "Metadata.Name":{
      "value": "custom name"
    }
  }
}
```

The controller method is defined like so:

```
public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody]DeploymentInput input)
{
...
}
```

We want to define a model that looks like so, with `DeploymentInput` referencing the outer object that is the `[FromBody]` input, and the `ValueString` representing a string that is stored insed the `"value"` property:

```
    public class DeploymentInput
    {
        public DeploymentProperties Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeploymentProperties
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        public ValueString Account { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fileLocation", Required = Required.Always)]
        public ValueString FileLocationUri { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, ValueString> Metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

Here, the parameters passed in with the prefix `"Metadata."`, would be added to the `Metadata` dictionary, with the keys `"ClientId"` and `"Name"` and the values as their corresponding `ValueString`s respectively.

I know we can implement our own model binding to do this, however is it possible to do this model binding using any of the in built framework? I see something similar is possible for [query and form based parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dictionaries-1) using prefix to specify the key and value, however when trying this from an input body, I see Metadata dictionary is null.

The things that we can control is how the properties under the `"Properties"` object are named, and how many of them there are.

Comment: `The things that we can control is how the properties under the "Properties" object are named, and how many of them there are.` You can try to include **ClientId** and **Name** properties in your **DeploymentProperties** class, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8hZ7.png).

Comment: These values are dynamic based on the customer making the request. so e.g. Customer 1 has configured their account to track "ClientId" and "Name", but Customer 2 could configure their account to track completely different Metadata that will be sent to us, e.g. *only* "SubscriptionId".

There is no bound on the Metadata properties that can be passed, hence wanting to use a dictionary for these parameters, but well defined parameter for the properties that our service enforces to be sent.